# Sync local storage from multiple pages

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

First, I'm sorry I don't know how to title the question better.

I'm making a Google Chrome extension whose purpose is to read table columns from a table on a **page A**. This happens in my **inject.js**:

```
var $tableRows = $("table tbody tr");
var offers = [];
var links = [];
$tableRows.each(function (index) {
    offers.push({
        code: $.trim($(this).find('td:nth-child(2)').text()),
        city: $.trim($(this).find('td:nth-child(6)').text()),
        state: $.trim($(this).find('td:nth-child(7)').text())
    });
    links.push($(this).find('td:first').find('a').attr('href'));

    if (index == $campaignTableRows.length - 1) {
        downloadPdfForOffers(offers, links);
    }
});
```

The code above creates an array that holds information that's in the table for those offers and saves the links for every offer profile.

Then the function `downloadPdfForOffers` does the following:

```
var downloadPdfForOffers = function (offers, links) {
    chrome.storage.local.set({"offers": offers}, function () {
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
            downloadUrlsReady: true,
            data: {links: links}
        });
    });
};
```

It sets in the local storage the current information I have for those offers and send the links to `background.js`.

Then from `background.js`, I open those links in new tabs.

```
if (request.downloadUrlsReady) {
    for (var i = 0; i < request.data.links.length; i++) {
        chrome.tabs.create({url: request.data.links[i], active: true});
    }
}
```

In my `inject.js` I'm waiting for the page to load the offer profile and with jQuery get the additional information I need and I send it to `background.js` again:

```
chrome.storage.local.get(["job_offers"], function (items) {
    if (items.job_offers && items.job_offers.length > 0) {
        var requirements = $("#j_id0\\:SiteTemplate\\:j_id747\\:j_id748").find('.margin-b3:first div.tcell:nth-child(2) div');
        var data = {
            file: {
                link: $('.btn.btn-link.btn-lg.vs2.margin-r2').attr('href'),
                name: $.trim($('#j_id0\\:SiteTemplate\\:j_id747\\:j_id767').text())
            },
            job_offer: {
                position: requirements.text()
            }
        };
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
            pdfUrlReady: true,
            data: data
        });
    }
});
```

Then in my `background.js` I update the already set offers and download the pdf:

```
if (request.pdfUrlReady) {
    console.log(request.data);
    chrome.storage.local.get(["job_offers"], function (items) {
        items.job_offers.forEach(function (job_offer, index) {
            if (job_offer.code == request.data.file.name) {
                items.job_offers[index] = $.extend(job_offer, request.data.job_offer);
                chrome.storage.local.set(items, function () {
                    chrome.downloads.download({
                        url: request.data.file.link,
                        saveAs: false,
                        filename: request.data.file.name + '.pdf'
                    }, function () {
                        chrome.tabs.remove(sender.tab.id);
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    });
}
```

The `console.log` there always has the full information I passed from the single page, however when I'm updating `chrome.storage.local` sometimes I get not complete information about the offer, probably because it's asynchronous.

How can I handle such situation?

Comment: Do you know devtools console shows references to variables so when you expand the object, the current value is shown, not the one at the time when console.log was used? Either use console.log(JSON.stringify(obj)) or set breakpoints and inspect the values by hovering the variables.

Comment: Yep. What I was trying to say is that `chrome.storage.local`'s **job_offers** get overwritten imo.

Comment: I think you can simply pass the data via sendMessage without using chrome.storage.